# How to maintain two tables data in a single page using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wanna fetch and show data from 2 tables on basis of invoice_id for one customer at one time. 
           shown

```
   invoice                                     invoice_description
 -------------                                ----------------------
invoice_no  name   address                   product  invoice_no  qantity
  789       adi    ghfgfgfgh                   a       789         1
  786       abc    sdsddasd                    b       789         2
```

I wanna output like this:-

If I click on 789 Invoice no.

```
                    invoice no-789               name-adi
                             product    quantity
                               a           1
                               b           2
```

but my output is like this:-

```
             invoice no-789   name-adi
                  product     quantity
                   a             1
                   b             2
         ------------------------------
              invoice no-786   name-abc
                  product     quantity
                    a           1
                    b           2
```

how to resolve it

controller:-

```
   //$id is current invoice_no;
 public function invoice($id)
    {

    $this->load->database();  

    $this->load->model('useradmin');  
    $query = $this->useradmin->selectdealer($id);
  $ids = $this->useradmin->selectdealer1($id);
  $data['dealers'] =  $query;
                    $data['id'] = $ids;

        $this->load->view('envoice',$data);
}
 model:-
    public function selectdealer($id)  
 {  

 $this->db->where('invoice_no', $id);
 $query = $this->db->get('invoice_description');
 return $query->result();  

}   
public function selectdealer1($id)  
{  

  $query = $this->db->get('invoice');  
  $this->db->where('invoice_no', $id);
  return $query->result();  

}   
 view:-
   foreach($id as $ids)
   {
     echo $ids->invoice_no;
     echo $ids->name;
      foreach($dealers as $dealer)
      {
       echo $dealer->product;

       }
    }
```

its returns all the data invoice_no and Name which present on my table
 second foreach loop works correctly but first foreach loop returns all the 
 data which present in table

Answer (score 1):

Use join query

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('invoice');
$this->db->join('invoice_description', 'invoice_description.invoice_no= invoice.invoice_no');
$this->db->where('invoice_no', $id);
$query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->result();
```

**For the second function**

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('invoice_description');
$this->db->join('invoice', 'invoice_description.invoice_no= invoice.invoice_no');

$query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->result();
```

Comment: but its return all the data from invoice table

Comment: join query for both function i have two function selectdealer($id) and selectdealer1($id) please explain it

Comment: If you don't need whole data from invoice table replace `$this->db->select('*');` with `$this->db->select('fieldName_1, fieldName_2, fieldName_3');`  @adil

Comment: I have updated my code. If the code works for flag it as right answer

Comment: it returns all row in the table

Comment: replace `$this->db->select('*');` with `$this->db->select('invoice_no , name');`

Comment: my selectdealer1($id) it returns all the row from the database i pass $id and i write where condition (invoice_no,$id) but its not working

Comment: i have upadated my code. just add that where condition `$this->db->where('invoice_no', $id);` after `$this->db->join` query. no need to replace `$this->db->select('*');`

Comment: Column 'invoice_no' in where clause is ambiguous

SELECT * FROM `invoice` JOIN `invoice_description` ON `invoice_description`.`invoice_no`= `invoice`.`invoice_no` WHERE `invoice_no` = '789'

Answer (score 0):

I have some suggestion regarding your code.
If you autoloading the database then you don't need to load it in the controller.
Use the constructor to load the common model in the controller.

#### controller code:

```
public function __construct() {
parent::__construct ();
    $this->load->model ('useradmin');
}

public function invoice($id)
{
    $this->load->database();  // if you autoloding the database then you don't need to load it here. if not then add this in __construct     
    $data = $this->useradmin->selectdealer($id);
    $this->load->view('envoice',['data'=>$data]);

}
```

#### model code:

You want a data related to id and name so I have added $name variable. you have to pass it to the model by your self or if don't then remove that line of code.

```
public function selectdealer($id)  
{ 

    $this->db->select('id.product, id.quantity');
    $this->db->from('invoice as i');
    $this->db->join('invoice_description as id', 'id.invoice_no= i.invoice_no');
    $this->db->where('i.invoice_no', $id);             
    $this->db->where('i.name', $name); // I have assumed this variable here so you have to take care of it or remove it if you don't need it.
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

    //You should use $this->db->last_query(); to get last executed query to understand the query properly. 
    // I am alos suggestion to use codeigniter log. it would be very helpfull. 

}
```

#### view code:

```
<?php
    foreach($data as $single_data)
    {
        // Your expected result i have printed it just for knowledge. remove it and do you further code.
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($single_data);
        echo "<//pre>";
    } 
?>
```

Hope it helps you.